# setting up wordpress into windows hosting

Tags: wordpress, hosting

I have an windows hosting. I have 2 questions:
1) Is that possible to set up wordpress in it? and second and important one is:
2) Is database really necessarry to set up wordpress? setting up without database like blogengine is possible?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Setting up on windows is possible. Try using Microsoft [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) to get started. For database, yes you absolutely need a database, specifically, MySQL.

Comment: I don't know offhand. My assumption would be that WebMatrix would create the web.config with all the necessary parts in place. Perhaps only the database settings would need to be updated?